# Conditional distinct filtering performance

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have javascript performance question. I need to count the unique occurrences of a property (`convId`) in an array of objects, where there's at least 2 unique other properties (`msgId`).

My dataset is large, about 100 000 objects in the array. With my script below, everything works, but it's incredibly slow on large datasets.

**The data and my slow script:**

```
// Note the convId and msgId are unique UUID values, only simplified below
// One unique convId can have multiple unique msgId, however -> this is what we want to count.
let data = [
   {
      convId: "abc",
      msgId: "111"
   },
   {
      convId: "abc",
      msgId: "222"
   },
   {
      convId: "def",
      msgId: "333"
   },
   {
      convId: "ghi",
      msgId: "444"
   }
]

let uniqueConvIdsWithAtLeastTwoMsgIds = 0;

// Filter unique convIds
let uniqueConvIds = [...new Set(data.map((a) => a.convId))];

// Loop through each uniqe convId and count unique msgIds
let uniqueMsgIds;
uniqueConvIds.forEach((convId) => {
  uniqueMsgIds = data.filter((a) => (a.convId === convId ? a.msgId : 0));
  if (uniqueMsgIds.length > 1) {
    uniqueConvIdsWithAtLeastTwoMsgIds = uniqueConvIdsWithAtLeastTwoMsgIds + 1;
  }
});

console.log(uniqueConvIdsWithAtLeastTwoMsgIds); // expected "1" as a result from the above data
```

Is there more clever way of doing this? I've thought of performing this within the `Set`, but I would still be looping and filtering again.

Many thanks!

Comment: why do you get `1`?

Comment: Because there's only one unique `convId`, which includes more than one unique `msgId`.

Comment: do you have always different `msgId` with same `convId`?

Comment: Indeed, both `convId` and `msgId` are UUIDs. I'll update the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a single loop for the data and count the occurences of same groups.

Then take another loop for getting the final count.

```js
let data = [{ convId: "abc", msgId: "111" }, { convId: "abc", msgId: "222" }, {  convId: "def", msgId: "333" }, { convId: "ghi", msgId: "444" }],
    counts = Object.create(null),
    result = 0;

for (const { convId, msgId } of data) counts[convId] = (counts[convId] || 0) + 1;

for (const key in counts) if (counts[key] > 1) result++;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, this really helps. The (correct) assumption of having always unique msgId and hence not the need to do more filters is pretty cool.